# Temporarily disable cuDNN in Caffe

Tags: caffe, cudnn

Is it possible to temporarily disable cuDNN in Caffe without having to set engine: Caffe on every single layer in my train_val file? We want to get a deterministic result for refactoring purposes but continue using cuDNN when we're not doing that.

Comment: what about setting mode to CPU?

Comment: I did that, but it still produced random results. I assumed that it was using cuDNN and just accessing the CPU with it, but maybe it's something else? I don't know.

Comment: You can recompile caffe without cudnn support. In the Makefile set `USE_CUDNN:=0` or with cmake `-DUSE_CUDNN=0`